# Qpid Broker-J Websocket Plugin AMQP 1.0

Tags: javascript, websocket, amqp, messagebroker, qpid

I'm trying to send AMQP 1.0 messages to a running [Qpid Broker-J](https://qpid.apache.org/components/broker-j/index.html) instance from within the browser with [rhea.js](https://github.com/amqp/rhea). I was able to send and receive messages with the node.js version.

I think I'll have to add/activate the [Websocket Plugin](https://github.com/apache/qpid-broker-j/tree/master/broker-plugins/websocket), I just can't find any documentation on where and how to do that.

Has anybody done that so far?

Here is my browser version snippet:

```js
var server = "ws://localhost:5673";
var client = require("rhea");

client.options.username = "guest";
client.options.password = "guest";

client.on("message", function (context) {
  console.log(context.message.body);
});

var ws = client.websocket_connect(WebSocket);
var connection = client.connect({"connection_details":ws(server, ["binary", "AMQPWSB10", "amqp"]), "reconnect":false});
connection.open_receiver("examples");
var sender = connection.open_sender("examples");

function send(body) {
  sender.send({ body });
}

function sendMessage() {
  console.log("sendMessage");
  const message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  send(message);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rhea@1.0.2/dist/rhea.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <button type="button" onClick="sendMessage()" />send</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this script I receive `Error during Websocket handshake`:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5673/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The plugin is activated already, you just have to add the port in the broker management web interface, or in the configuration directly. For anybody who is looking for it, look under Broker > Ports > Add Port.